# disabling more that one element in a page by cover overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some elements in one page which I want to have cover overlay on those in order to disable those elements.

I have an ajax call which in success, I used the `coverWithOverlay($('.disable'));` to disable all the elements that have `.disable` class.

Here is the function:

```
function coverWithOverlay($element) {
        var pos = $element.offset();

        var $overlay = $('<div class="inside"></div>').attr({
            title: 'this is disabled'
        }).css({
            position: 'absolute',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            opacity: 0.5,
            top: pos.top + 'px',
            left: pos.left + 'px',
            width: $element.outerWidth() + 'px',
            height: $element.outerHeight() + 'px'
        });

        $(document.body).append($overlay);

        return $overlay;
    }
```

It works if I have just one element in the page. How can I investigate that to several elements?
Some pages have one some pages have more than one elements to be disabled.

Comment: A jsFiddle would help us help you. Also, have you considered the CSS [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) property?

Comment: why this `return $overlay;`?

Comment: yes, It shouldn't return overlay. I just used that for something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try something like this?

```
function coverWithOverlay($elements) {
    $($elements).each(function () {
        var $element = $(this);
        var pos = $element.offset();

        var $overlay = $('<div class="inside"></div>').attr({
            title: 'this is disabled'
        }).css({
            position: 'absolute',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            opacity: 0.5,
            top: pos.top + 'px',
            left: pos.left + 'px',
            width: $element.outerWidth() + 'px',
            height: $element.outerHeight() + 'px'
        });

        $(document.body).append($overlay);
    });
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/23FtA/

---

That being said, [jQuery BlockUI plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element) will be a more generic way to do this.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/X5DfK/

Comment: This jquery Block UI helps but why the mouse pointer is always busy on that?

Comment: @Mark: the busy cursor shows that the page is doing some action, if you want a normal cursor, just add this css  `.blockUI.blockOverlay{cursor: default}` to your page

Comment: Ok, that is perfect. But is there any css, for jqueryBlockUI which I can change the background color of that?

Comment: @Mark: `$.blockUI({ overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#00f' } });` have a look here http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos